# Asp.Net Core Convert UTC (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD) input to LocalDateTime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I an working with an MVC .Net Core API that injests a DateTime value as YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD. However when it posts the data to the SQL database it comes out as YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.s. (example of issue below)

**Input**

`2020-01-21T17:05:30.3416751-05:00`

**What Gets Written to the Database**

`2020-01-21 22:05:30.343`

Given that the input format specifies the timezone with the -05:00 in the case of the input example, how would I ensure the value is converted to local before writing to the database?

I have tried looking at altering my ModelBuilder in the Context constructor, but this works great for EntityFramework, but not for EntityFramework Core.

Comment: Do you use SQL Sever or something else? What column type of date in database?

Comment: Yes, I use SQL Server. The Column type is just DATETIME, when I try using Datetime offset it doesn't leave the "-05:00" on the field, it just re-converts the column to YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.s and always appends a +00

Comment: `DateTime` is a timezone aware class and also it will round the date to closest rounded value. Have you tried using `DateTimeOffset` class instead of `DateTime`. It will probably solve your problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Just try to discard TimeZone information like this:

```
// Parse date string to DateTimeOffset
var DateTimeWithOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-01-21T17:05:30.3416751-05:00"); // 21.01.2020 17:05:30 -05:00

// Or Parse exact
// var DateTimeWithOffset = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2020-01-21T17:05:30.3416751-05:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

// Leave only DateTime ignoring it's offset, which makes DateTime local
var DateTimeLocal = DateTimeWithOffset.DateTime; // 21.01.2020 17:05:30
```

Then insert `DateTimeLocal` to the database.

This solution won't work if You need to keep TimeZone information in the database.

Answer (score 0):

So I added the following to context constructor

```
        var dateTimeConverter = new ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>(
            v => v, v => DateTime.SpecifyKind(v, DateTimeKind.Local));
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime) || property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?))
                    property.SetValueConverter(dateTimeConverter);
            }
        }
```

And that converted the input to local time.

**However,** I found that the input wasn't what I thought it was. I was really getting the input time as UTC on the API side. The client application I'm sending data to the API through had a custom xml serializer in place that was converting the time to yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-stzd. So my issue was on the client side not on the API side.

**Bonus:** I'm being told that DB columns should always be UTC and to leave it as is anyway. It's on whoever is turning the DB values to a report to convert the column values to local time from UTC.